# Why does my collRect array isn't getting items?

Tags: javascript

I joigned recently a fullstack course.
It's going great so far(even tho it's really hard), even in JS where I used to be stuck a lot.. Well, that's what I tought, right now I'm totally lost on an exercice.

Can anyone check this fiddle and tell me where my mistake(s) is ?

The goal of the exercice is to make a classe (rectangle), a method to check collision (that's ok), the part where I have a problem is where I need to check the collision of 1000 rectangles of random sizes, their creations is okay but the check is where I am stuck.

```
let randomRect = [];
let collRect = [];

function colCheck(n) {


    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        randomRect[i] = Rectangle;
        Rectangle = {};
        Rectangle.name = "Rectangle " + i;
        Rectangle.topLeftXPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        Rectangle.topLeftYPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        Rectangle.width = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        Rectangle.length = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

        randomRect.push(Rectangle);
    }
    for (let j = 0; j > n; j--) {
        if (randomRect[i].collides(randomRect[j])) {
            collRect.push(Rectangle);
            console.log("Collision detected")
        }
    }
}
colCheck(1000);
console.log(collRect);
```

The collides method is on the jsfiddle.
Sorry if I made some spelling mistakes.

Here's my fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ou5wyrp8/3/

Comment: `for (let j = 0; j > n; j--) {` `j` will never be `> n` if `n` is positive, so you'll never go into the body of the loop. If you meant to loop backward, do `for (let j = randomRect.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {` You can use the debugger built into your browser and/or IDE to see the problem. On a browser, for instance, open devtools, go to the "Sources" or "Debugger" pane, and click in the left-hand side of the beginning of that `for` loop to set a breakpoint. Then step through the code.

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense... `randomRect[i] = Rectangle;` ??? `Rectangle = {};` ??? you don't even create any rectangle in your code... if you got a class object, you need to construct it with `new`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback guys, and sorry if the code didn't make any sense.. I'll try my best to enhance my skills, a long journey ahead :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I started to make some edits to push you in the right direction. Your first mistake was the way you try use a class. When creating objects from classes, you want to use the `new` keyword, the class name, and then treat the class name as a function. Note that the function the executed when using new is the constructor e.g

```js
let newRect = new Rectangle(topLeftXPos, topLeftYPos, width, length)
```

Next, there was problems in your for loop. For starters, I assumed that you wanted the j loop to be nested inside the i loop, which it was not.

I went as far to fix these two things. All that is left is for you to loop through `randomRect` and push collisions to `collRect`

```js
class Rectangle {
    constructor(topLeftXPos, topLeftYPos, width, length) {
        this.topLeftXPos = topLeftXPos;
        this.topLeftYPos = topLeftYPos;
        this.width = width;
        this.length = length;
    }
    collides(otherRectangle) {
        if (this.topLeftXPos === otherRectangle.topLeftXPos) {
            return true;
        }

        else if (this.topLeftYPos === otherRectangle.topLeftYPos) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

let randomRect = [];
let collRect = [];
function colCheck(n) {


    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        //populate randomRect
       let newRectangle = new Rectangle(
         //top
         Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
         //left
         Math.floor(Math.random() * 10), 
         //width
         Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
         //length
         Math.floor(Math.random() * 10))
        randomRect.push(newRectangle);
    }
    console.log(randomRect)
    for( let i = 0; i <n;i++){
      for (let j = n-1; j > 0; j--) {
          if (randomRect[i].collides(randomRect[j])) {
              collRect.push(randomRect[i]);
              console.log("Collisaaaion detected")
          }
      }
    }
}
colCheck(1000);
console.log(collRect);
```

Comment: Oh man, thanks ! I've been stuck on this for 2 days without seen where my mistakes were... I'm sorry if these sounded dumb to you all guys, i'm at the very beginning of my journey here and I've had to do this exo 2 days after the beginning of the JS course. 

Anyway, i think i understand the logic now. Thank you :)